# How get previous values form last transaction using PK and FK

Tags: sql, t-sql, union

I have this SQL Queries,

```
SELECT PaymentID, CustomerID, PaymentDate, Amount, Balance, Credit 
FROM Payment 
WHERE (PaymentDate = '2012-11-03')
```

I also like to print previous Balance and Credit form last transaction of the customer.
This is my try.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 Balance, Credit, PaymentID 
FROM Payment 
WHERE CustomerID = '??' AND PaymentID < '??'
ORDER BY PaymentID DESC
```

As you can see this does nothing as Queries are not liked.
I think I have I have to use T-SQL or UNION but have no idea How to implement it.

#### This kind of Output I am trying to achieve.

[image]

#### Payment Table

```
PaymentID   int 
CustomerID  varchar(50)
PaymentDate date
Amount  decimal(18, 2)
Balance     decimal(18, 2)
Credit  decimal(18, 2)
```

#### Note:

This is for all the customers not only for single customer, it's like a sale Report.
There are can be more than one payment per customer in a day.

Comment: are you doing it for all customers or a single customer?

Comment: @codingbiz This is for all the customers not only for single customer, it's like a sale Report.

Comment: You need a LEFT JOIN to the second query and a PARTITION OVER to select top 1 from each group in the second query

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server is this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started

```
SELECT P1.paymentID, P1.CustomerID, P1.PaymentDate, max(PP.paymentID)
FROM Payment P1 
Join Payment PP 
  on PP.paymentID < P1.paymentID 
 and PP.CustomerID = P1.CustomerID
 and P1.PaymentDate = '2012-11-03'
GroupBy P1.paymentID, P1.CustomerID, P1.PaymentDate


not test but I think this will pull in the other data

select PC.*, PL.PaymentDate,  PL.Amount,  PL.Balance,  PL.Credit 
from 
(SELECT P1.paymentID, P1.CustomerID, P1.PaymentDate, max(PP.paymentID) as PriorPID
FROM Payment P1 
Join Payment PP 
  on PP.paymentID < P1.paymentID 
 and PP.CustomerID = P1.CustomerID
 and P1.PaymentDate = '2012-11-03'
GroupBy P1.paymentID, P1.CustomerID, P1.PaymentDate) as PC 
join Payment PL 
  on PL.paymentID = PC.PriorPID 
 and PL.CustomerID = PC.CustomerID
```

Comment: It work fine if I change Where to Having, however how do I select previous Balance and Credit  using max(PP.paymentID) 
I have tried 
... max(PP.paymentID), pp.Balance, pp.Credit
I Get this error  
Column 'Payment.Balance' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Knowing you get the correct max(PP.paymentID) helps.  The next step is derived table with a join to get those values.  I will look at it in the AM.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will be awaiting :)